# Removed a package, its still installed... wine

Tags: wine

```
kevin@Kevins-PC:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get remove wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils libcapi20-3 libgif4 libmpg123-0
  libnss-winbind libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libpam-winbind odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 ttf-droid ttf-umefont ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc winbind
  wine-gecko1.4 wine1.4 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wine
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
After this operation, 21.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 158269 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wine ...
kevin@Kevins-PC:~/Desktop$ wine
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
kevin@Kevins-PC:~/Desktop$ wine --help
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
kevin@Kevins-PC:~/Desktop$ wine notepad
```

Why is wine still there if I just removed it?

Answer (score 1):

apt-get says it all:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils libcapi20-3 libgif4 libmpg123-0
  libnss-winbind libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libpam-winbind odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 ttf-droid ttf-umefont ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc winbind
  wine-gecko1.4 wine1.4 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

Run `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Package wine1.4-i386, which holds the `wine` executable,  will be removed.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. To many walls-o-text seen today. Fell on blind eyes.